# Scala statements and Expression - Var vs Val

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, var

This works fine in the Scala REPL:

```
scala> var g,h = 20
g: Int = 20
h: Int = 20
```

But, in an InteliJ worksheet with just `var g,h = 20`, I get an error:

```
Error:(1, 6) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : (T1, T2) required: Int var (a,b) = { 20;};}
```

If I change it from var to val, it works fine. What's going on?

Comment: Can you share your method and class  defination ? I belive you are not running it from main method.

Comment: it doesn't have main method. executing .sc file from Intelli j IDE

Comment: Error:(1, 6) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Int
var (a,b) = { 20;};}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you are running it from a plain `.sc` file.  The syntax is valid . Try it from a `main(..)` method or something like below . It works

```
object Main extends App {

var g,h = 20
println(g)
println(h)

}
```

Comment: Getting below error message in IDE Error:(1, 6) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Int
var (a,b) = { 20;};}

Comment: Are you running it from main method?

Comment: running from .sc file without main method.  single lines of code

Comment: No.. not from main method.. if i am rewritting with val, it is working fine

Comment: Please run it like i mentioned.

Comment: copied above code snippet into .sc file . it is giving "defined module Main".. how should i call ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180245/discussion-between-learn-hadoop-and-balaji-reddy).